# SQL server 2014 delete and insert

Tags: sql-server-2014

I creating a data mart system where i should pull some data from another system and push it here.To insert into data mart tables I am writing a procedure, which will be run by EOD. Initially all the data will be pushed, later for subsequent pulls only modified or newly added will be pushed into my tables.
My Procedure should be fast in terms of performance. This is what I have written. I wanted to know any other best way.

```
 SET @rowCount = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ST_Student)
  IF(@rowCount ==0)
BEGIN
       -- Insert all 10000 records
END
ELSE
BEGIN
      Delete from table where ID is exist.

      Insert all newly added records,( max 10 record)

END
```

What is the best to do this. So that I can ignore two transactions.

Comment: which sql Database are you using?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using! (That code is very product specific.)

Comment: `MERGE` comes to mind

Comment: SQL server 2014

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong but if you are deleting all the records in the table that already exists wouldn't it be more efficient to truncate?

Comment: Deleting will be only the audited records by EOD. For example initially data mart will have any records in the table. So first condition will check and finds row Count is 0 , So all the records from another system will insert into data mart.(example, 20000)  . Lets say this happened yesterday(24-05-2017).  Today on wards only the modified records or newly inserted i will be getting (Lets us say 10 records). So No need to Truncate the table.